# BitTorrent test case failing with libsodium

Tags: digital-signature, bittorrent, libsodium

I'm trying to run the test vector as described in [BitTorrent BEP 44](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html) test #1, but I'm not creating the same signature as they do:

305ac8aeb6c9c151fa120f120ea2cfb923564e11552d06a5d856091e5e853cff
1260d3f39e4999684aa92eb73ffd136e6f4f3ecbfda0ce53a1608ecd7ae21f01

Instead, the signature I create using libsodium is:

c44ad65291c2b1087218db8a43e3fa7b73cfa01b585b0ff9e6b962ed50e701a1
6065277417ff5bbae43d9b76e52129d27bf2e33e8b043ea67ace7ff91dae4d02

Using this code:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sodium/crypto_sign.h>

// Test vector #1 from http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html
// Using libsodium.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* buf = "3:seqi1e1:v12:Hello World!";

    const char* sk =
        "\xe0\x6d\x31\x83\xd1\x41\x59\x22\x84\x33\xed\x59\x92\x21\xb8\x0b"
        "\xd0\xa5\xce\x83\x52\xe4\xbd\xf0\x26\x2f\x76\x78\x6e\xf1\xc7\x4d"
        "\xb7\xe7\xa9\xfe\xa2\xc0\xeb\x26\x9d\x61\xe3\xb3\x8e\x45\x0a\x22"
        "\xe7\x54\x94\x1a\xc7\x84\x79\xd6\xc5\x4e\x1f\xaf\x60\x37\x88\x1d";

    unsigned char signature[crypto_sign_BYTES];

    crypto_sign_detached(signature,
            NULL,
            (const unsigned char*) buf,
            strlen(buf),
            (const unsigned char*) sk);

    char signed_buf[crypto_sign_BYTES * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(signature); ++i) {
        sprintf(signed_buf + i*2, "%.2x", signature[i]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", signed_buf);
}
```

Seems to be something silly I'm missing, but I just can't see it.

Comment: have you checked whether the private key computes to the same pubkey as indicated by the spec?

Comment: I have since found the answer, but haven't had time to answer it here. Apparently there are (at least) two different formats for private keys. The first format is called `ref10` and is used by libsodium. The second format is `ref10` transformed with a one way function as explained [here](https://github.com/orlp/ed25519/issues/10#issuecomment-242761092). If someone beats me to a concise answer with an example using [these functions](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/src/libsodium/include/sodium/crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch.h) I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/orlp/ed25519/issues/10#issuecomment-242761092) there appear to be (at least) two different formats for private keys. One of them is called `ref10` and it is the one used by libsodium. It's composed of 32 bytes of *seed* concatenated with another 32 bytes of *public key*.

I couldn't find the name of the other format, but - as also explained in the above link - it's basically the *seed* hashed with `sha512`. More precisely

```c
void ref10_to_lib(
        unsigned char *private_key,
        const unsigned char *ref10_private_key)
{
    sha512(ref10_private_key, 32, private_key);
    private_key[0] &= 248;
    private_key[31] &= 63;
    private_key[31] |= 64;
}
```

The BitTorrent specification uses the second format and to be able to use it, one must use the deprecated [`crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch`](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/f6cab99f64864c83bce03072a31e37355fad94d6/src/libsodium/include/sodium/crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch.h) function instead of `crypto_sign_detached` as such:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sodium/crypto_sign.h>
#include <sodium/crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch.h>

// Test vector #1 from http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html
// Using libsodium.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* buf = "3:seqi1e1:v12:Hello World!";

    const char* sk =
        "\xe0\x6d\x31\x83\xd1\x41\x59\x22\x84\x33\xed\x59\x92\x21\xb8\x0b"
        "\xd0\xa5\xce\x83\x52\xe4\xbd\xf0\x26\x2f\x76\x78\x6e\xf1\xc7\x4d"
        "\xb7\xe7\xa9\xfe\xa2\xc0\xeb\x26\x9d\x61\xe3\xb3\x8e\x45\x0a\x22"
        "\xe7\x54\x94\x1a\xc7\x84\x79\xd6\xc5\x4e\x1f\xaf\x60\x37\x88\x1d";

    unsigned char signature[crypto_sign_BYTES];

    crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch(
            signature,
            NULL,
            (const unsigned char*) buf,
            strlen(buf),
            (const unsigned char*) sk);

    char signed_buf[crypto_sign_BYTES * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(signature); ++i) {
        sprintf(signed_buf + i*2, "%.2x", signature[i]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", signed_buf);
}
```